# What's the difference between cy.readFile and cy.fixture?

Tags: javascript, cypress

What is the difference between [cy.readFile](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile.html) and [cy.fixture](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html)?

It looks like that they both do pretty much the same thing: Yields the content of a file. Except that `cy.fixture( ... )` looks inside the `fixture`-folder and `cy.readFile( ... )` looks from the project root.

---

And if both could be used, are there then pro's/con's by using one of the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is conceptual, but there are some [practical considerations](https://www.karltarvas.com/2020/10/25/cypress-cy-readfile-vs-cy-fixture.html) as well.

Fixtures are meant for files that are used **only** for your tests, e.g. placeholder test data, sample responses and so forth. In other terms, fixtures are files that would not be a part of your project if you didn't have tests.

For this end, fixtures provide some [convenience utilities](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Notes), such as piping them directly into [`cy.route()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html):

```
cy.route('GET', '/users', 'fixture:users');
```

[`readFile()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile.html) on the other hand is a generic method that you can use to read more or less anything. It is a good candidate if you need to read files that are a part of your regular project code, e.g. translations:

```
cy.readFile('translations/en_US.json').then(...);
```